# Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

While delivering to integration stream , Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files and fails.

As PDF files no need to be merged, how to solve this?

Is it a defect in Clearcase UCM? any work around is there or some policy settings needs to be set to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to merge a specific type of file, you can change its type to a "copy merge" policy (ClearCase will copy the source over the destination)

```
cleartool find . -name '*.jar' -exec 'cleartool chtype "COPY_MERGE" $CLEARCASE_XPN'
```

This is an improvement from the NEVER_MERGE presented in [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0424_hu/), and is available in [ClearCase 7.x](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21240740).

You can create a custom ["FILE_COPY_MERGE" type as described here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK46684):

```
cleartool mkeltype -supertype compressed_file -mergetype copy -nc FILE_COPY_MERGE
cleartool chtype FILE_COPY_MERGE 'element'
```

A more complete example is [detailed in this technote "**Handling binary files in ClearCase**"](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123371):

[image: copy merge]

Comment: Other alternatives options (`merge -ndata`) in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14491867#14491867