# Clearcase error reports

Tags: clearcase

Is there a way to mute or remove error messages from a Clearcase command such as `mklabel`? I'd like to suppress error messages from the `mklabel` command if possible.

Comment: You could just redirect stderr output to `/dev/null` ?

Comment: I just tried that, and it worked to a certain degree. I'm using the Clearcase plugin for Jenkins, and the errors from my `mklabel` command are the only things causing the job to fail. I know the `mklabel` command is labeling everything I need, but Jenkins continues to fail the job. I was hoping that the redirection would solve that issue, but it doesn't. Jenkins still fails the job.

Comment: @rafafan2010 what error message does the mklabel generates in your Jenkins job?

Comment: Several errors in this form: `cleartool: Error: Unable to access "/view/RPL_CSL_Main/vob/ms2_rpl/lost+found": No such file or directory.` I have deliberately excluded elements using a `-none` selection rule, and I don't want those elements to be labeled. Yet, the command still tries to label them. I think that generates the error which causes Jenkins to fail the job.

Comment: @rafafan2010 can you try (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8794738/6309) a `element /myVob/lost+found/... -none`, keeping `lost+found`, but excluding its content? (`/...`). For you: `element /vobs/ms2_rpl/lost+found/... -none`. I suppose the `/vob` was a type: it should be `/vobs/xxx`.

Comment: It didn't do anything when I changed the config spec and ran the command again. By the way, I'm doing this in a Dynamic View, in case that changes anything.

Comment: @rafafan2010 no, dynamic view is fine. Do you mean you get the exact same error message? and did you use `/vob` or `/vobs`? Was it a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts you see in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014127591) (or [this one](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013727632), or in [one of the ten best scripts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html#N102F4)) usually employ the same technique:

```
cleartool mklabel ... 2> /dev/null
```

In a perl script for instance:

```
my $cout = `cleartool desc $pn@@\/$lbtype 2>/dev/null` ;
```

This is part of [`cleartool` output redirection techniques](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425#redirect-output).

I prefer redirecting `stderr` in a file, that I can parse (after executing the command) to detect rare errors, while ignoring all the warning (like label already existing and moved).

But the main idea remains: for a [`cleartool mklabel`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm), there is no `-silent` or `-quiet` option.