# How to check the status of delivery from one stream to its parent stream in Clear case for Windows?

Tags: clearcase

How to know details on the status(in-progress or finished) of a delivery from one stream to its parent stream?

I came across this when I was trying to deliver from C stream to B stream. But it throws error that B has a deliver in progress and I have to wait till it is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get any more information than "deliver is in progress" with a graphic deliver (or a [`cleartool deliver -status`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm))

At most, adding the `-l` option (`-long`) would display a list of versions that may require merging.

I like to at least check the current activity in the destination stream (B stream): it will be a [deliver activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732330/6309), which can at least tell you who started the deliver (owner of the activity) and when.

```
cleartool lsact -stream B@\aPVob -cact
```

In any case, you would need to complete or cancel the deliver, before being able to start another one.
Or you would need to find the owner of that deliver, in order for him or her to complete or cancel it.

As I [recommended before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8794738/6309), try to complete the deliver (especially if some merged versions have already been checked in), before trying to cancel the deliver.