# ClearCase; Deliver with overwrite

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

Suppose streams `A` and `B` both are seeded from baseline `bl_C_5` of some stream `C`. From there parallel developments goes in `A` and `B` and some point the baseline at `A` is `bl_A_3` and in `B` is `bl_B_6`. At this point is it posible to deliver `bl_B_6` from `B` to `A` so that `A` will now contain an exact copy of `bl_B_6` (without being merged with `bl_A_3`)? In other words is it possible to completely overwrite a stream with delivery operation? If not, is there any other way or command for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "copy merge" isn't supported at the deliver operation (it can be [supported at the type level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789258/clearcase-ucm-is-trying-to-merge-pdf-files/8789593#8789593), by associating a "copy-merge" policy, but that isn't practical when you want to merge *everything*)

One way to quickly do a "copy-merge" is to:

- start the deliver as usual
- instead of completing right away, start a `clearfsimport -rmname` from a view on the source Stream to the destination view (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416875/creating-a-new-subdirectory-structure-in-clearcase/418196#418196) for instance, and [man `clearfsimport`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm)): you will get a mirror image of Stream `B` on stream `A`.
- complete the deliver
- checkin whatever file is still in checkout.