# How to exclude binaries from being delivered?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Recently i was asked to deliver interproject delivery.

While delivering lot of merge request was popped for even binaries.

I skipped them and did draw merge arrow one by one. It was nerve breaking work.

Is there any way to exclude binaries from being merged or some command line option to draw merge for all the binaries?

( I am using clearcase UCM)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change their type manager to a type with the option "copy on merge" (or never merge, if you really don't want them merged at all).

That type manager inherit from compressed_file, but would resolve any merge by copying the source version over the checked out destination version.

See [Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789258/clearcase-ucm-is-trying-to-merge-pdf-files/8789593#8789593http) as an example.
You also have the IBM technote: "[Handling binary files in ClearCase](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123371)".

So you have the choice between:

[image: never merge]

or:

[image: copy on merge]

Comment: Note: this doesn't depend on using UCM or base ClearCase.