# asking for merge in clearcase even if not required

Tags: clearcase, branching-and-merging

I have been merging from one merge to an integration branch for some time. It always shows some files for merge needed, But they are not needed since there is no difference between the version in source branch as well as destination branch. is there any way to get rid of this? at the moment, i manually undo checkout those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still merge those, or ClearCase will keep proposing them on the next merge.

If you do merge them, that will draw a merge hyperlink between the source and destination version of those files, and they shouldn't be present in the next merge.

If we are talking about a certain type of file, you also can modify the type manager merge policy, as in "[Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789593/6309)".

Comment: its a normal file not any special one. and I cannot merge because even if it says merge required, source and destination are same.do you mean checkin even if identical to predec?

Comment: @user2636464 yes, `ct ci --identical`, and see if it pops up on the next merge.